# How to add newline when printing json array using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

Here's my json file:

```
"ref": [
            "https://owasp.org",
            "https://www.acunetix.com",
            "https://cwe.mitre.org"
        ],
```

I using jquery to set value by id in my html code. Here's my html file:

```
<p id="objDetail"></p>
```

Here's my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("<?php echo base_url('filejson.json') ?>", function(data) {
            var ref = data.ref;
            $("#objDetail").text(ref);
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log("An error has occurred.");
        });
    });
```

i want to add newline when printing json array from ref object. The result of the code above is :

```
https://owasp.org,https://www.acunetix.com,https://cwe.mitre.org
```

How to get the result like this :

```
1. https://owasp.org
2. https://www.acunetix.com
3. https://cwe.mitre.org
```

Thank you.

Comment: _"How to get the result like this :"_ - Don't just dump the array with `.text()` into the DOM. Use a `<ol>` and add every element in the array as `<li>` into that list.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Andreas. Use a `<ol>` and add every element in the array as `<li>` into that list

```js
        
var ref = ["https://owasp.org", "https://www.acunetix.com", "https://cwe.mitre.org"];

var $ol = $("<ol></ol>");

$.each(ref, function(index){
    var $li = $("<li>" + ref[index] +"</li>");
    $ol.append($li);
});

$("#objDetail").append($ol);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="objDetail"></p>
```

Comment: thank you for it @Akshay, i've got idea for another code style to DOM json array object from your answer